# Why did almost every ancient civilization have a found religion?

Tags: ancient-history, religion, new-world, anthropology

I'm studying to be an Anthropologist and I've always had this question but I cannot get a definitive answer. Almost every ancient civilization I have studied, whether it be in the Old or New World had some sort of religion. Why did all of them think that there was a higher power or powers? Why is it so consistent throughout the world?

Comment: Because apparently it's an innate trait of humans to attribute the unknown to supernatural entities.

Comment: Because it is nonsense - Confucianism is NOT a religion, and China is one of the greatest civilizations. But set of morals, of course MUST exist. Because it IS the civilization. Read Gumilev.

Answer (score 1):

We can't know for sure, because our information is so scanty about very early civilisations. The two obvious possibilities are:

- Humans have an innate tendency to invent explanations for things they don't understand, and to treat them as having personhood.
- Rather than being innate, this happened to be a cultural value among early humans, and has been passed down to us since then.

It's extremely hard to distinguish between these possibilities at this distance in time. While experiments *could* be designed to distinguish between them, they would involve bringing up newborn children without human contact. This is considered profoundly immoral, and thus the experiments should not be done.

Comment: I did always think that humans might just have the tendency to create an explanation for their world/lives.
I did find out that there was a tribe in Africa that had no religious belief, rituals, superstitions or any type of burial rites which I found was very interesting.
In regards to the experiment you mentioned, that would be very interesting but again highly immoral.